# Recursively create directories for all letters

Tags: bash, recursion, directory

I would like to create a folder structure based on a brace expansion such as `{a-z}`. Each string generated by the brace-expansion should be a new folder. Furthermore, each of these folders should contain the same set of subfolders similarly generated. And this up to a given level.

An example for the range `a-z` and depth 16

```
a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/
a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/b/
a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/c/
...
d/a/h/r/y/d/s/b/e/y/k/f/o/o/q/c/
...
z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/y/
z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/z/
```

The following code allows me to go upto depth 2:

```
for x in {a..z} ; do mkdir -p $x/{a..z} ; done
```

But how do I go further?

Comment: I think you may run out of inodes before you're able to create all of those directories.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I want to create such folder structure for testing some defensive techniques. and some security test.

Comment: @Tech2K A suggestion: Please edit your question and add the reason you just game me to your question (if it makes sense). Then remove your comment, I will also remove mine. This way everyone benefits (by not being forced to read all the comments.)

Comment: @Tech2K : There are 26 letters in the alphabet, and you want to create a directory structure to a depth of 16, with all combinations of these letters. This means that you are going to create 43608742899428874059776 directories. Better getting yourself some crossword puzzle, so that you have something to do while the directories are being created....

Comment: @user1934428, also take the comment of acro444 into account. Furthermore, creating a directory also takes space. Even if it would only be a single byte, that amount of directories require `4.9E9 TB` of disk space.

Comment: @kvantour : I was thinking of this, but even assuming that the OP runs a quite fast system which would allow to create 10000 directories per second, it would take approximately 138282416601 years to finish his task, so he has plenty of time to await the arrival of hard disks with enough capacity to accomodate such a huge file system. A bigger problem would be that in the meantime, our sun would have been turned into a Red Giant, swallowing the Earth. Therefore it is advisable do the whole thing on a laptop computer, which is easier to carry to a neighbour solar system when the time comes....

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution. Job is called with 2 params: `max_depth` and `base_path`

```
#!/bin/bash

function job()
{
    local depth=$(($1-1))
    local path=$2
    local x
    for x in a b c # reduced for test
    do
        mkdir -p "$path/$x"
        ((depth>0)) && job $depth "$path/$x"
    done
}

job 3 ./test
```

Proof it with:

```
find test -type d
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest form would be to use any of the following lines:

```
mkdir -p {a..c}/{a..c}        # depth 2
mkdir -p {a..c}/{a..c}/{a..c}  # depth 3
mkdir -p {a..c}/{a..c}/{a..c}/{a..c}  # depth 4
...
```

The brace-expansion will make all combinations and `mkdir -p` will take care of the rest.

Of course, you do not want to type this over and over for various sets. So you could generate the full brace-expansion-string with bash and use `exec` to process the brace-expansion-string before passing it to `mkdir -p`:

```
depth=3
set={a..c}
dirs=$(printf "/${set}%.0s" $(seq $depth))
mkdir -p $(eval echo .${dirs})
```

Be aware however that if your set has length `m`, and you want a depth of `n`, you are creating `m^n` directories. This number could conflict with the number of arguments you can pass on to a program.

**Related information:**

- [What is the maximum allowed depth of sub-folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516816/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-depth-of-sub-folders)
- https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: While it works, the `}` in printf line is a typo / not needed. (it is added to the last number `1 2 3}`, but because of `%0.s` it is ignored).

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, that was from an earlier test where I did `{1..2}` instead of the `seq` thing.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive funcion may solve your problem. Take care with inodes generation when using high directory levels...

```
#!/bin/bash

function createDir {
   mkdir -p $1 && cd $1;

   for x in {a..z} ; do
         local i=$(($2-1))
         [ $i -lt 0 ] && continue;
         createDir $x $i
   done

   cd ..
}

createDir $1 $2
```

Save into a file, like `mkdir.sh`, and call it: `./mkdir.sh <main_folder> <level>`.